# Can You Redeem a PSN Code for a Game You Already "Own" through PS Plus?

Tags: psn, playstation-plus

If you get a "freebie" game via Playstation Plus and later decide that you want to own the game independently of your subscription, can you enter a code for a game (say from Amazon) while your PS Plus subscription is still active? What if your subscription lapses, can you then buy/redeem a code for a game?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You cannot purchase a game that is already listed on your current PSN account as "Purchased" (which these free games are). You would have to wait until your subscription expires or make a separate PSN account.
2. I sort of answered this in part 1, but yes, if your sub is no longer active you are free to purchase any games you had for free on PS+ (otherwise they would essentially be locking people out of buying certain games if they choose to no longer use PS+, which would just be a terrible business model).

Some info found from [this post.](http://community.us.playstation.com/t5/Games-Services/Buying-games-that-ps-plus-gives-for-free/td-p/40139969)

Comment: It is disappointing that you can't directly buy a game you got through PS+, but according to that post it seems you might be able to if it comes in a bundle. I wonder if you buy a code from Amazon for a game that you got for "free"from PS+, if PSN will let you redeem it and own the game indefinitely. Any notion?

Comment: @P.M. - Hmmm... Interesting question. It's possible and I would *hope/think* that's what would happen. Worst case scenario, I would think that they don't let you redeem, but your code would not expire (I'm not 100% sure on this) and you could just redeem whenever your subscription ends.

Comment: It appears that you cannot. I have a code for a game I already got through PS+, and when I try to confirm the use of the code after inputting it and being shown the information about the game it is for, I get the error "The code you entered may not be correct or may no longer be valid. Please check your entries."