# Can I buy a PS4 game if I own the free version?

Tags: ps4, playstation-plus

Say I have a PS4 subscription and a free monthly game. What happens if I decide to cancel my subscription, but decide to buy the previously free game (so I won't need the subscription to play it).

Can I buy a game outright without getting the 'you cannot buy this because you already own...' error?

Comment: Do you mean to say you already got the PS+ monthly rotation game and you wanna play it after cancelling your subscription or do you mean to say you didn't get it during its rotation and you wanna buy it afterwards?

Comment: I mean I had a subscription and got a free game while on it. Then if I decide to cancel the sub can I completely wipe the free version from my library history so I can download the game again ( and pay for it). Sometimes it says 'you cannot download because you already own...'

Comment: [Can You Redeem a PSN Code for a Game You Already “Own” through PS Plus?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/257160) answer this. I don't really know if it should be marked as a dupe.

Comment: @Lemon I think it should.

Answer (score -3):

This is quite the question, one you would assume Sony would allow for maximum gain. With that said, it might be more beneficial for Sony to force you into buying their proprietary subscription service over buying a third party product where they only see marginal gains. And, considering they already sunk the costs of getting those games on PS+, those games might now be contractually ineligible for resale for players who already took advantage of the offer. This is one of those predicaments where you'd like Sony to play the intuitively consumer friendly hand and eat the loss, but maybe that's too good to be true. It certainly could be an oversight as well, or a architecture problem on the backend (a la PSN name changes). I've seen this asked many times over the years (ie playstation forums, neogaf, ign, etc etc), but unfortunately as of right now, there is no way to make the transaction after you add it to your library.